# How remove background from an image work?

Tags: web-frontend

When building my website, i faced an image with some text in it.

But the text only display when i changed background-color to black.
After some research, i think ít's a transparent image, and we have some online tools to replace background image.

Anyone know how  **remove background from an image** really work ?

And why it make the text showed up ?

[This is my image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pawab.png)

updated: Sorry, my question is not clear. Here is my code

https://codepen.io/ging2507/pen/wvWJeyR

when i remove comment of navbar, the Text of image show up(not the normal text 123131). And i dont know why this happened

```
.navbar {
  background-color: #14425D;
}
```

Comment: You should add z-index:-1 to your Image so it goes under another elements or add z-index: 100; to your Text to bring it before your Picture.

Comment: Are you really asking why you can't see white text on a white background?

Comment: @Quentin Yes ! And why add background to image work,, it modify the image or something like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image doesn't change at all. It just has some pixels that are marked as transparent.

Consider a sheet of glass. Paint on it using white paint. Put it on a sheet of white paper. Now you can't see what was painted on it. Replace the white paper with black paper. Not you *can* see what was painted on it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. You have an image that you want to remove the grey background from? I have tried to use [this tool](https://www.remove.bg/upload) and this is the following output that I got. The text cannot be read since it is it white and blends together with the background. I hope this helped

[image: Transparent background image]

Edit: The tool that I have posted can also replace the background  as you can see here
[image: background replaced]

**EDIT**
You can also use CSS to add background to the image.
I have mananged to add linear gradient to the image using CSS. You can see the code

```css
.logo {
  background: linear-gradient(
    105deg,
    rgba(34, 193, 195, 1) 0%,
    rgba(253, 187, 45, 1) 100%
  );
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pawab.png" alt="some logo" class="logo">
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a link to [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/) if you want to play around with it.